# Using INSTR (oracle function) in Simple.Data

Tags: oracle, simple.data

How to use INSTR with simple.data

I need to add a condition while joining 2 tables

```
select * from table A inner join table B on INSTR(A.Column , B.Column)>0
```

How to write this query using Simple.Data (c#)?

Answer (score 0):

I can't test right now if this will work, but try:

`db.A.FindAll().Join(db.B).On(db.A.Column.INSTR(db.B.Column) > 0);`

Comment: Sorry, I can't test with Oracle at the moment. You could look at using Simple.Data.RawSql to execute hand-coded SQL but still get Simple.Data's dynamic results back.

Comment: Thanks.. will try that